# Selenium Python No Element Name

Tags: python, html, selenium

Hey I have the following html code I'm trying to scrape in Python's Selenium library:

```
Event ID: <font color='blue'>8YG411</font>
  Action - Citation / Fine
  Notice to facility: <font color='blue'>12/18/2013</font>
             Appeal: <font color='blue'>N/A</font>
  Action Cease/Recind: <font color='blue'>1/28/2014</font>
         Case Closed: <font color='blue'>1/28/2014</font>
  Initial Amount: <font color='blue'>$2500</font>
Event ID: <font color='blue'>PUJU11</font>
  Action - Citation / Fine
  Notice to facility: <font color='blue'>10/28/2011</font>
             Appeal: <font color='blue'>N/A</font>
  Action Cease/Recind: <font color='blue'>5/22/2012</font>
         Case Closed: <font color='blue'>5/22/2012</font>
  Initial Amount: <font color='blue'>$2000</font>
```

I have tried next sibling element from Event ID to get the actual event ID with no success.  There is also changing structure for the xpath for the event ID from page to page.  Let me know if anyone has any thoughts.  The page is here: http://www.in.gov/isdh/reports/QAMIS/ltccr/cr004353.htm

My failing code below:

```
loopNum = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(., \""+ "Event ID" +"\")]/following-sibling::*")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your html structure use following xpath to get id `8YG411`

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@summary='Enforcement Actions']/following-sibling::font[1]").text
```

Comment: Thanks! This was perfect!